# After I changed gmail password, heroku logs error when user tries to send message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, smtp

After recently changing my password, my app does not let users send messages which are directed to my gmail. Or maybe, my gmail is possibly not accepting messages from my application? My heroku logs are reporting the following error:

**`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.)`**

I have tried:

• updating the password in the `application.yml` file I generated using Figaro.

• `heroku restart`.

• ensuring the `Allow less secure apps:` is set to `ON` in gmail.

• enabling/disabling `enable_starttls_auto: true`.

I can see through the heroku console that the message is being saved in the production table. Again, the problem is the message is never received in gmail. This problem is only in production and NOT in development.

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module ChrisPelnarDotCom
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            ENV["gmail_username"],
      password:             ENV["gmail_password"],
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true  }
    end
end
```

**setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port  => 587,
  :domain  => 'www.yourdomain.com',
  :user_name => ENV["gmail_username"],
  :password => ENV["gmail_password"],
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = ENV["gmail_username"]
```

**config/application.yml**

```
gmail_username: "my_email@gmail.com"
gmail_password: "my_password"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to update the password in the `gmail_password` environment variable in production using `heroku config:set gmail_password=YOURNEWPASSWORD --app YOURAPPNAME`. `application.yml` should only be getting used in development.